# Counter variable not updating correctly

Tags: javascript

EDIT:
As several of you pointed out, the "submit" type reloads the page each time, so a running count is not maintained. I fixed this by using sessionStorage to store the number. Here's the fixed code:

```
function addItem(){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('count',Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count'))+1);
    /*if(currentItems>3){
        currentItems=3;
    }*/
    console.log("Item added");
    update();
}
  
function removeItem(){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('count',Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count'))-1);
    /*if(currentItems<0){
        currentItems=0;
    }*/
    console.log("Item removed");
    update();
}
  
function update(){
    console.log(Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count')));
}
```

Original Question:
I don't have much experience in JS so forgive me if this is a silly question. I created the following script to count the number of items added to a bundle of products:

```js
var currentItems=0;
function addItem(){
    ++currentItems;
    /*if(currentItems>3){
        currentItems=3;
    }*/
    console.log("Item added");
    update();
}
  
function removeItem(){
    --currentItems;
    /*if(currentItems<0){
        currentItems=0;
    }*/
    console.log("Item removed");
    update();
}
  
function update(){
    console.log(currentItems);
}
```

The addItem and removeItem events are triggered by "onclick" tags on certain buttons. When I check the console, it correctly shows the "Item added" and "Item removed" messages, but it displays the wrong number for currentItems. When I click a button that should trigger addItems, the console displays 1 regardless of how many items I've added. Similarly, when I click a button that triggers removeItems, the console displays -1. It seems like the variable is starting from 0 each time I click. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT:
Here's the full code. I'm building a custom template within the Bundle Builder Shopify App, so everything aside from the CSS styling and my script are default.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .product-box {
        display: flex;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        margin-left:15%;
    }
    .product {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .note-field--container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .bundle-content{
        width:20%;
        float:left;
        margin-right:5%;
    }
    #outside-progress{
        background-color:grey;
        width: 30%;
    }
    #inside-progress{
        background-color:#202945;
        height:30px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
const selectedVariants = new Map();

function setAddDisabled(form) {
    const variantId = form.querySelector('[name="variant"]').value;
    const sectionId = form.querySelector('[name="section"]').value;
    const canAdd = window.BundleBuilder.canAddVariant(variantId, sectionId);
    form.querySelector('[type="submit"]').disabled = !canAdd;
}


/* Change variant price after variant change */
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.bundle-builder--add-to-bundle-form select[name="variant"]'),
    function (select) {
        select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            const variantId = e.target.value;
            selectedVariants.set(e.target.id, variantId);
            const price = e.target.querySelector('option[value="' + variantId + '"]').dataset.price;
            e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.variant-price').textContent = price;

           const form = e.target.parentElement;
           setAddDisabled(form);
        });
    }
);


function render() {
    selectedVariants.forEach(function (variantId, selectId) {
        const select = document.getElementById(selectId);
        if (select) {
            select.value = variantId;
        }
    });
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.bundle-builder--add-to-bundle-form'),
        setAddDisabled,
    );
}
    
/* Change variant to what was selected last */
document.body.addEventListener('bundlebuilder:render', render);
render()
  

  

</script>

{% if bundle.published %}
    <h1>{{ bundle.current_section.name }}</h1>
    <div id="outside-progress">
      <div id="inside-progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-box">
        {% for product in bundle.current_section.products %}
            <div class="product">
                <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
                <img src="{{ product.image.src }}" />
                {% add_to_bundle_form bundle.current_section %}
                    {% if product.available_variants.size > 1 %}
                        <select name="variant" id="select-{{ bundle.current_section.index }}-{{ product.id }}">
                            {% for variant in product.available_variants %}
                                <option value="{{ variant.id }}" data-price={{ variant.price | money }}>
                                    {{ variant.title }}{% if variant.available_count %} (available: {{ variant.available_count }}){% endif %}
                                </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    {% else %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="variant" value="{{ product.available_variants[0].id }}" />
                        {{ product.available_variants[0].title }}{% if product.available_variants[0].available_count %} (available: {{ product.available_variants[0].available_count }}){% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <span class="variant-price">{{ product.available_variants[0].price | money }}</span>
                    <button type="submit" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#202945;" onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
                {% end_add_to_bundle_form %}
                {% for variant in product.variants_in_bundle %}
                  {% change_quantity_form %}
                      {% comment %}{{ variant.title }}{% endcomment %}
                      <input type="hidden" name="variant" value="{{ variant.id }}" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="section" value="{{ bundle.current_section.index }}" />
                      <button type="submit" name="remove" onClick="removeItem()">-</button>
                          {{ variant.count }}
                      <button type="submit" name="add" onclick="addItem()">+</button>
                  {% end_change_quantity_form %}
               {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% if bundle.has_next_section %}
        {% section_switch_form %}
            <input type="hidden" name="section" value="{{ bundle.current_section.index | plus: 1 }}" />
            <button type="submit" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#202945;">Next</button>
        {% end_section_switch_form %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if bundle.has_prev_section %}
        {% section_switch_form %}
            <input type="hidden" name="section" value="{{ bundle.current_section.index | plus: -1 }}" />
            <button type="submit" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#202945;">Previous</button>
        {% end_section_switch_form %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if bundle.errors.size > 0 %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in bundle.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="bundle-content">
        {% if bundle.content.items.size == 0 %}
            <span>Your bundle is empty</span>
        {% else %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Variant</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in bundle.content.items %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.variant.product.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.variant.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.variant.price | money }}</td>
                        <td>
                            {% unless item.is_required %}
                                {% remove_from_bundle_form item %}
                                    <button type="submit" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#202945;" name="remove" onclick="removeItem()">Remove</button>
                                {% end_remove_from_bundle_form %}
                            {% endunless %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if bundle.content.price < bundle.content.compare_at_price %}
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Discount</th>
                        <th>
                            <span>{{ bundle.content.price | minus: bundle.content.compare_at_price | money }}</span>
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                    <th>
                        <span>{{ bundle.content.price | money }}</span>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            {% if settings.note_enabled %}
                <div class="note-field--container">
                    <label>{{ settings.note_label }}{% if settings.note_required %} (required){% endif %}</label>
                    {% note_field %}{{ settings.note_text }}{% end_note_field %}
                </div>
                {% if settings.note_prompt_visible %}
                    <div class="note-field--error-message">
                        <p>Note required before adding to cart.</p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% add_to_cart_form %}
                {% if bundle.subscription_type == 'optional' and bundle.subscription_frequencies.size > 0 %}
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="subscription-enabled" value="0" />
                        One-time purchase
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="subscription-enabled" value="1" />
                        Subscribe
                    </label>
                {% endif %}
                {% if bundle.subscription_type == 'required' or bundle.subscription_enabled %}
                    {% for frequency in bundle.subscription_frequencies %}
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="subscription-frequency" value="{{ frequency.id }}" />
                                    {{ frequency.frequency }} {{ frequency.unit }}
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
                    Email: <input type="email" required name="subscription-email" value="{{ settings.subscription_email }}" />
                {% endif %}
                <button type="submit"{% unless bundle.can_add_to_cart %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %} style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#202945;">
                    {% if bundle.adding_to_cart %}
                        Processing...
                    {% else %}
                        Add bundle to cart
                    {% endif %}
                </button>
            {% end_add_to_cart_form %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>Sorry, this bundle is currently unavailable.</p>
{% endif %}

<script type="text/javascript">
/* Custom Progress Bar */
const progress = document.getElementById("inside-progress");
var currentItems=0;
function addItem(){
    ++currentItems;
    /*if(currentItems>3){
        currentItems=3;
    }*/
    console.log("Item added");
    update();
}
  
function removeItem(){
    --currentItems;
    /*if(currentItems<0){
        currentItems=0;
    }*/
    console.log("Item removed");
    update();
}
  
function update(){
    console.log(currentItems);
}  
</script>
```

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/5n1cdwrb/)  Can you update the question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I can’t replicate the issue. Please may your share a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: `button type="submit"` - You wouldn't happen to be doing this within a form that's submitting to the server and thus reloading the page, would you?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited the post to include all of the code from the template

Comment: @David Could that be the problem? How can I work around the reloading of the page to keep a consistent count?

Comment: @fhos98: Use `type="button"` so it doesn't submit a form.  Possibly even don't use a form at all, if you don't need one.  The code in the question has gone from not enough to far too much, so it's difficult to be certain if that's the problem.  But yes, if you are observing that the page is reloading then that would explain why the counter is reset each time.

Comment: @David Would changing the type from "submit" to "button" interfere with how the elements pass information to the server? I think the form is necessary as that code was supplied by the app and I imagine is needed to pass user input to the server. After looking into this further, it seems like others are suggesting to store this number to localstorage. Would that be a viable solution without altering the forms?

Comment: @fhos98: Depending on what you are trying to do, sure.  If you *want* to submit a form and reload the page when clicking on either of these buttons then, yes, you would need to persist that value somewhere outside of the page code itself in order for the value to survive a page reload.  Local storage is an option, the server is an option, etc.  Again, the overall intent of all of the functionality present (and the rest which may not be present here) is unclear.  But the bottom line is that variables don't retain their values between page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addItem(){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('count',Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count'))+1);
    /*if(currentItems>3){
        currentItems=3;
    }*/
    console.log("Item added");
    update();
}
  
function removeItem(){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('count',Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count'))-1);
    /*if(currentItems<0){
        currentItems=0;
    }*/
    console.log("Item removed");
    update();
}
  
function update(){
    console.log(Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count')));
}
```